# If the distance between any two points is less than $1$, must $X$ be compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $X$ be a complete metric space such that the distance between any two
points is less than $1$. Then is $X$ necessarily compact?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it's not. Consider an infinite space with distance $d(x,y) = \frac12$ if $x\neq y$.

Comment: For any metric and any constant $b>0$ there is a topologically  equivalent metric bounded by $b$.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Topological equivalence need not preserve the completeness of the space, which is one of the assumptions in the problem.

Comment: @user103254 indeed, thank you for pointing this out. The construction that I had in mind preserves completeness, though: replace $d$ by $(x,y)\mapsto\mathrm{min}\{b,d(x,y)\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Sir, would this be true if we assume $X$ is closed i mean... do we have compactness if $Y$ is closed subspace of a metric space $X$ in which distance between any two points is less than $1$ then can we say $Y$ is compact? Please help me sir..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik No, it would in general not hold. It is a very special property of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that every closed and bounded (with respect to the Euclidean metric) subset is compact.

Answer (score 4):

Daniel Fischer already gave a counterexample:

Define the metric 
$\displaystyle d(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1/2,\quad &x\ne y \\ 0, \quad &x= y\end{cases}$

on any infinite set $X$. The completeness follows from the fact that any Cauchy sequence is eventually constant. And $\{\{x\}:x\in X\}$ is an open cover with no finite subcover.

I'll add a less "pathological" example: the space of all continuous functions  $f:[0,1]\to [0,1/2]$ with the metric $d(f,g)=\sup_{[0,1]}|f-g|$. Completeness holds because uniform convergence preserves continuity. Compactness fails because, for example, the sequence $f_n(x)=x^n/2$  has no uniformly convergent subsequence. (Where would it converge to?)

Answer (score 1):

The result is true (by [the Hopf-Rinow theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem#Variations_and_generalizations) for metric spaces) if you are willing to add two supplementary conditions: 1) $X$ should be locally-compact; 2) $X$ should be a [length space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric).